# Calculate the difference between two times in python

Tags: python, time

I am using python, and want to calculate the difference between two times.

Actually i had scenario to calculate the difference between login and logout times,
for example in organizations there is some particular limit for working hours, so
if a user login at `9:00 AM` in the morning and if he logs out at `6:00 PM` in the evening,
we need to calculate how much duration he stayed in the office(which is `9 hours` in the present scenario ), but i want to do this in python, so can anyone please let me know how to achieve the above concept of calculating the difference between login and logout times ?

Comment: You are computing the difference between two dime *deltas*, not two points in time?!?

Comment: delta = change, you are comparing to changes in time

Comment: k sorry but my concept is calculating the time duration of login and logout times actually

Comment: Then try to fix your code above, don't use a `timedelta` to represent `time`.

Comment: sorry about my typing in the question, but all about my intention is to calculate the time duration of login and logout times, can anyone implement this in python ?

Answer (score 20):

```
>>> start = datetime.datetime(year=2012, month=2, day=25, hour=9)
>>> end = datetime.datetime(year=2012, month=2, day=25, hour=18)
>>> diff = end - start
>>> diff
datetime.timedelta(0, 32400)
>>> diff.total_seconds()
32400
>>> diff.total_seconds() / 60 / 60
9
>>>
```

Comment: you can print `str(dif)` instead of diff.seconds/60/60 to get a nicer format.

Comment: If you are logged in for more than a day you'll want to use `diff.total_seconds()`

Comment: How we can provide hours value here for example a user logged in at 9 AM and logs out at 6PM ?

Answer (score 5):

use [divmod](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod) for this task

```
>>> start = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
>>> end = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
>>> divmod(end - start, 60)
(0, 2.454) # (minutes, seconds)
```

divmod will give

Comment: divmod() is very useful to convert the time seconds in the needed time in minutes and or hours.

Comment: divmod doesnt support datetime or timedelta objects.  You need to use end.seconds and start.seconds

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong classes to represent time in the first place.

```
> import datetime
> print datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1)
55 days, 14:11:06.749378
```

The *returned* object is a `timedelta`. But the difference is of course computed between `datetime` objects.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion @Fabian's answer is probably the best.  But are we making this more difficult than it has to be?

Do you need to calculate it by day, month, year?

If you are generating this, wouldn't it be easier to just use a timesec representation?

When a user logins in:

```
user_login_time = time.time()
```

When the user revisits:

```
time_difference = time.time() - user_login_time
```

Then check to see if the time_difference is above XXXX seconds?  now I am **assuming** that you are just going to check if the user hasn't logged in XX minutes, or xx hours?

Otherwise, I would stress that @Fabian's answer would be the best, if you are looking at parsing time date strings, or needing to do other time/date functions with the data.

I would also stress, that if you use this method, to make constants for the times, or make sure to comment them, to make it more readable.

But if your simply just trying to find out if the user has been on within the last 30 minutes, this might be easier.