# How to calculate time until certain clock? python

Tags: python, time, date-arithmetic

I need to create a basic program, where the user is asked to type in, what time does his/her bus leave and then the program tells him/her, how much time is left.
The problem is I can't get the program to do the calcualations. Done a lot of google searches and still nothing. English is not the best, so sorry.

Here's my code so far:

```
import time
import datetime
format="%H:%M"
timenow=time.strftime(format)         #is this correct?
print("What time does your bus leave?")
busleaves=input()
bus=time.strptime(busleaves, format)   #is this correct?
timeleft=datetime.datetime(timenow, format)-datetime.datetime(bus, format)  #is this the right way to do the calculation???
```

After that I need to output the result in a sentence "Your bus leaves in xx hours and xx minutes". I know how to use *print()*, but how do I separate hours and minutes from *timeleft*?

I'd be really thankful if you could help me out, I've been messing with this for ~6hrs, trying different solutions from google but nothing has worked so far. :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate the difference between two times in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067710/calculate-the-difference-between-two-times-in-python)

Comment: Does your code run? Does it give you the results you're looking for? If not, what, if any, error message do you get? Have you tried debugging by printing the values of the different variables to see if they are correct? There is still a lot you have to do.

Comment: What is your specific issue? *"Done a lot of google searches and still nothing"*, *" I've been messing with this for ~6hrs, trying different solutions from google but nothing has worked so far. :/"*  is not very informative. If you run your code; you should see errors. If you don't know how to fix them; ask (include the errors in the question).