# Difference between two times in Python

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

```
import datetime

baslangicAni = datetime.datetime.now()
baslangicSaati = datetime.datetime.strftime(baslangicAni, "%X")

bitisAni = datetime.datetime.now()
bitisSaati = datetime.datetime.strftime(bitisAni, "%X")

gecenSure = bitisSaati - baslangicSaati
print(f"Geçen Süre: {gecenSure}")
```

I want to find the difference between two times in seconds, but I can't find it.

Comment: You are transforming datetima into string, and so string minus string doesn't make sense. Just keep numeric varsion. `datetime` module has also a deltatime class

Comment: Do you mean the difference in seconds between two *times* such as 09:30 and 11:45?

Comment: @jarmod Yes, I wanted to write as you wrote.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15067787/271415

Comment: @jarmod I've been researching for 2 hours but I didn't understand anything. Anyway, thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: If you have two datetime objects (do you?) subtract the earlier from the latter. The result is a `datetime.timedelta` object. Call its `total_seconds()` method to get the difference in seconds. What is it specifically that you don't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.total_seconds()` of the timedelta object you get, when you substract one datetime from a second one.

```
import datetime
first_date = datetime.datetime.now()
second_date = datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1)

difference_in_seconds = (first_date-second_date).total_seconds()
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, but the app also takes the millisecond into account, I just wanted to take the sec. into account.

Comment: Anyway, thank you again because even so, the app worked the way I wanted. If there is a method that takes seconds into account without taking milliseconds into account, I would appreciate it if you let me know.

Comment: Seems like there is no default, but there are a few options listed here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470627/how-do-i-remove-the-microseconds-from-a-timedelta-object